# PList Information (other than title and subtitle) in calloutAccessoryControlTapped Detail VIew (iOS)

Tags: ios, xcode, annotations, plist, android-mapview

I'm having trouble calling information from a plist in a Detail View Controller from a calloutAccessoryControlTapped method. I can bring up the title and subtitle (in UILabels i the Detail View Controller) values since they are built into the mapView already but I'm trying to also bring up a phone number to the corresponding annotation that's clicked. All the information is typed out in a PList file which I've used to place pins and call up information on the map.

I understand this is a bit of a broad question but I'm just trying to get pointed in the right direction since I can't seem to find any good tutorials or references for what I'm trying to do. If anyone has any ideas on any material to read or can help me get started, it'd be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

---

Here's is some test XML code from my PList (it's set up the same way, the content is just edited).

```
<dict>
    <key>Root</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>Address</key>
            <string>123 Main St., New York, NY 55555</string>
            <key>Latitude</key>
            <real>80.133069</real>
            <key>Longitude</key>
            <real>-99.512423</real>
            <key>Phone Number</key>
            <string>(212) 555-5806</string>
            <key>Title</key>
            <string>Test #1</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Address</key>
            <string>321 Main St., Los Angeles, CA 90046</string>
            <key>Latitude</key>
            <real>38.887794</real>
            <key>Longitude</key>
            <real>-56.302544</real>
            <key>Phone Number</key>
            <string>(310) 555-7792</string>
            <key>Title</key>
            <string>Test #2</string>
        </dict>
```

Comment: can you edit your question to show what your plist looks like? where do you want the phone number to appear in the annotation?

Comment: Well I don't want the phone number to appear in the annotation, I want it to appear in the Detail View that's called when clicking on the annotation. I'll edit the question to show you what the plist looks like.